# Conditional nested forms with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, clients and client_prices, I would like to have 2 client prices nested forms sections in the client's show page. 1 nested form would be for non-custom prices and another for custom prices. The non-custom (custom == false) prices would only have the "custom" attribute available to edit. The "Custom Prices" would have all of the attributes available to edit.

I've tried a few different approaches, but I don't know where to put the conditional logic to make this work correctly. I'm using simple_form to generate the forms, but I'm not married to it.

**Controllers**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :client_prices_attributes
    has_many :client_prices
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_prices, :allow_destroy => true

end


class ClientPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :client_id, :price, :visit_type, :id, :custom

  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :default_price

end
```

**Client Show page**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @client do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :client_prices do |def_price_form| %>
        non-custom prices form here
    <%end%>
    <%= f.fields_for :client_prices do |def_price_form| %>
        custom prices form here
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Do you want to have different fields in the nested form depending on the value of attribute `custom` from nested model?

Comment: Possibly. Ideally the "custom" checkbox would not be available or would be hidden if it was set to true, in which case it would be in the Custom Prices section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @client do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :client_prices do |def_price_form| %>
    <%= if def_price_form.object.custom %>
      Here you fields for custom form      
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```